# Unity - error CS0117 about AnimationMode and GetCurveBindings

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I just open a project using Unity **2019.2.13f1**. This Project was previously created using Unity **2020.1.0a14**

However, I got below error:

> Library/PackageCache/**com.unity.timeline**@1.2.3/Runtime/Utilities/**AnimatorBindingCache.cs**(91,40): error **CS0117**: **'AnimationMode'** does not contain a definition for **'GetCurveBindings'**

any idea to solve this error?

Thank You...

Answer (score 1):

Update the Unity to the version 2019.3.0f1 to solve the problem. Also update Timeline package in Package Manager (Window / Package Manager).

Answer (score 0):

go to **Package Manager**, find the package having the error (com.unity.timeline in this case) and remove it to force Unity to download the package version matching the editor